# Perl one-liner Authen::Passphrase::MySQL323

Tags: perl, command-line

I have this nicely performing one-liner

```
cat "$1" | perl -MDigest::SHA1=sha1_hex -lpe '$_ = sha1_hex $_'
```

and I wanted to use a different module for creating mysql323 hashes.

```
cat "$1" | perl -MAuthen::Passphrase::MySQL323=hash -lpe '$_ = hash $_'
```

however my very limited understanding of perl one-liners fails...
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Authen::Passphrase::MySQL323](https://metacpan.org/pod/Authen::Passphrase::MySQL323) does not provide a functional interface. You need to create an object and call a method.

This is part of the synopsis in the docs. I suggest you read them to figure out which method you need, and how you need to initialize it for your purpose.

> ```
> $ppr = Authen::Passphrase::MySQL323->new(
>     hash_hex => "2af8a0a82c8f9086"); 
> $hash = $ppr->hash;
> ```

In general, it would look like this in your one-liner, which unfortunately becomes a bit longer.

```
cat "$1" | perl -MAuthen::Passphrase::MySQL323 -lpe '$_ = Authen::Passphrase::MySQL323->new(hash_hex => $_)->hash'
```

Change the argument to `new` and the method that's called as needed.

Comment: so I tried your example but it doesnt seem to work :-(( echo "mypass" | perl -MAuthen::Passphrase::MySQL323 -lpe '$_ = Authen::Passphrase::MySQL323->new(hash_hex => $_)->hash'  results in "mypass" is not a valid hex MySQL v3.23 hash at -e line 1

Comment: @Sebastian As I said, you might need to use a different argument for the constructor. I didn't read up on how this specific encryption works. Probably it's `passphrase`. Check the docs, please.